# Search questions based on two tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

I want to propose a feature:

*search for questions based on two tags.*

**Why is this needed?**

*There are a lot of `tags` that are about a topic which cannot be independent*.

For example, let's assume I'm a C# programmer, who is master at arrays.

Let's say I want to answer a C# question about arrays. How can I find one? I can search for a question in the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, however, the chances of me finding a question about [array](/questions/tagged/array) are very small. Sure, I can go ahead and search in the [array](/questions/tagged/array) tag, but then I will also find questions about Python arrays, Java arrays, JavaScript arrays and so on.

To sum up:

**So the fact that it is impossible to search based on a question with two tags or more is preventing peoples with knowledge about a specific topic to reach people with then same-topic questions**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Barrays%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=1

Comment: You can just do that! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags+search for example ;)

Comment: am I just wrote all this for nothing?

Comment: @avidgood2 well, at least you took the time to write something ;) I've seen worse :P But essentially, yeah. This is already possible so there's no need to request this as a feature, and how to do this search is already explained in the question Glorfindel linked...

Comment: Your question led me to find [a minor bug in the Search Results page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330672/295232). Which showed me there was [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330673/295232) in the Ask Question page. So you helped me find two bugs, thanks a lot!

Comment: @avivgood2 no, it’s now good documentation for anyone else who doesn’t realise it’s possible.