# Search Results page title doesn't 'understand' search options

Tags: bug, status-review, search, window-title

When using the [`is:q` search option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) (= questions only), the Search Results page correctly notes I'm using a search option, but the page title thinks it's a regular search term: it shows "Posts containing 'is:q'".

[image]

Comment: Was just about to post this. I tried all search options and the page title treats all of them as string literals, with the exception of tags.