# New "Similar questions" widget is not responsive enough

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, responsive-design, similar-questions

When I ask a question in a small browser window, the question titles aren't visible, so I can't really determine if my question has already been asked before:

[image]

Comment: Reproduced while browsing via phone. This is bad indeed.

Comment: No-repro on FF Android, Samsung S9+, One UI 1.0. I [opened FF in a pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pmTN.jpg) and reduced the size to as small as possible. That's zoomed out as far as possible (the screen isn't cutoff, I can drag sideways to see the rest; and of course I can scroll down), except for the annoyance that the width isn't correct (different bug/neglect) the ' "Similar questions" widget' looks quite good, and far more usable than what is depicted in your screenshot. You have permission to use that image if you wish to add it to your bug report.

Comment: Reproduced Chrome 53 (I run an old version because of changes they made to the new tab screen that I vehemently dislike) on Android 4.4.

Comment: Maybe a related issue: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386796/new-similar-questions-box-is-too-small

Comment: Can you still reproduce this?

Comment: @Shog9 [looks like it's status-completed ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE4mG.png)